# IIS 8.5 Redirecting

Tags: iis-8

I have a basic project running on IIS 8.5

```
sites 
-> test.domain.com
--->virtualPath
----->index.html
```

On the browser when enter https://test.domain.com/virtualpath, it is return 301 (redirect) to test.domain.com/virtualpath/

I don't have any URL Rewrites in IIS configuration. Just trying to figure out why it is redirecting to test.domain.com/virtualpath/

How can avoid this 301 redirect?

Comment: same thing if you enter an endslash?

Comment: @Joel If I enter with the slash (https://test.domain.com/virtualpath/) not redirect.

Comment: You can enable FRT to track where the 301 response comes from, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: `when enter https://test.domain.com/virtualpath, it is return 301 (redirect) to test.domain.com/virtualpath`, these two urls are the same, you can clear your browser's cache and try again, if the situation is still the same, you can use failed request tracking to view detailed request information.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that IIS doesn't handle extensionless URLs very well. URLs are processed based on the file extension, otherwise it's presumed to be a directory you're looking to get served. The normal convention however is to omit the `index.html` file.
But most services like IIS take that for granted, and if nothing is specified, it will lookup if there's a `/index.html`.

Lets take a simple example:

```
google.com
```

In reality what's being served to you is:

```
google.com/index.html
```

Lets take your request as an example `https://test.domain.com/virtualpath`

```
test.domain.com
- virtualPath/
  - index.html
```

As you can see, you're essentially trying to get a directory rather than a specific file. It's up to IIS to try to find and understand that you want a file instead of a directory now. That's why you're getting a `301`. It's redirecting you to the `/index.html` file.